C++ - Creating curvilinear gridlines of a 2D cartesian plot using Qt
I want to create a plot with gridlines like so:

with just the grey lines and not the background.
I also want the graph to be adjusted according to different lengths of y-axis and x-axis like so:

What is the best way to go about this using Qt?
Link for the above pictures: https://debug-docs.readthedocs.io/en/test/notebooks/visualisation/wradlib_plot_curvelinear_grids.html

Recommendation: Get rid of the word "best" because it's a moving target. To get "best" you need to know (and tell us)  a lot about the target system, and it rarely ports to other systems without becoming "Not best". Plus you almost never need "best", so the time spent attaining anything above "meets requirements" is time you could have spent with your fiends and family or working on other projects for fun or profit.

Adding to what written above, anyone of us could have their own opinion on their best, which could also be in contrast to your best. Using the standard Qt library, I can think of at least two "main" ways to achieve this (painting with QPainter on a custom QWidget, or using the Graphics View framework, and each one of them, in turn, may then be achieved with different approaches. There are many ways, only you could eventually decide "the best". Start familiarizing with the aspects above to begin with, then do a proof of concept and see for yourself.
